# Cloudwatch rule that trigger SNS in case pattern do NOT match completely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to create CloudWatch Rule that triggers SNS, when pattern do NOT match completely?

With following example I hope that question will be more clear:

```json
{
 "source": [
  "aws.ec2"
 ],
 "detail": {
  "eventSource": [
   "ec2.amazonaws.com"
  ],
  "eventName": [
   "RunInstances"
  ]
 }
}
```

Additionally I want to specify region: `"awsRegion": "eu-central-1"` but (here is tricky part) want SNS to be triggered when `awsRegion` is NOT `eu-central-1`.

Idea is to receive a notification when someone makes a mistake and runs an instance in the wrong region.

Also will add more rules once I know how to do, so the question is not exactly for the region, but general.

Thanks in advance!

TeoVal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to trigger when a pattern does NOT match.

You will have to receive notifications for all regions on your SNS topic and implement your own logic with a Lambda function subscribed to your topic (or directly with Lambda as a target).

Also note that it's possible to restrict users from making API calls in specific region using a policy similar to the following (restricts call to `us-east-1` and `eu-central-1` regions):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RegionsRestriction",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "us-east-1",
                        "eu-central-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```